# MVC3 validate name and provide list of selections on form

Tags: ajax, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I'm very new to MVC and trying to find my way around. I am also coding in VB so having some difficulty there, as most examples are in C#. But I have soldiered on...however, I am currently completely stuck on this one. I have searched for days and tried so many variations, I don't even remember half of them.

This is what I am trying to accomplish: I have a form to enter an employee service action (i.e. onboard, terminate, transfer, etc.). On the form the user will enter a manager first and last name. I need to validate that name against AD and if it is not found, return a dropdown list of possible matches for them to select from.

I'm trying to do this with Ajax and a partial view and have not had good results. Currently I get an error:

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Emp_Mgr_Name'
```

It also is trying to load this when the form initially loads - I don't want it to do this until they have actually entered in the manager name on the form.

Here is what I have so far - where am I going wrong, or is what I'm trying to do not possible and does anyone have any suggestions for how I might accomplish this? Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

In my main view, these are my script references:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"          type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And here is the script to validate the manager name and return the list (this is firing and calling the action in my controller):

```
$("#Emp_Mgr_Last_Name").change
  (function () 
  {
    $.getJSON("/EmpInfo/ValidateMgrName/" + $("#Emp_Mgr_First_Name").attr("value") + "/" + $("#Emp_Mgr_Last_Name").attr("value"),
    function (data) 
    {
      $("#ValidateMgrName").html(data)
    });
  });
```

Here is the code in my controller (`strADList` does contain a list of names when this runs):

```
    <HttpGet()>
    Public Function ValidateMgrName(ByVal Emp_Mgr_First_Name As String, ByVal Emp_Mgr_Last_Name As String) As ActionResult
        Dim strADList As New List(Of String)
          If Request.IsAjaxRequest Then

            Dim strADInfo = GetADInfo(Emp_Mgr_First_Name.Trim, Emp_Mgr_Last_Name.Trim)
            If strADInfo <> String.Empty Then

            Else
                strADInfo = GetADList(Emp_Mgr_First_Name.Trim, Emp_Mgr_Last_Name.Trim, strADList)
             End If

            Return Json(New With {.success = True, .data = strADList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet})
        End If


    End Function
```

In my main view, here is where I am trying to do the replacement code with the partial view:

```
    <div id="ValidateMgrName">@Html.Partial("ValidateMgrName")</div>
```

And this is what I have in my partial view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Emp_Mgr_Name")
```

Comment: Update - I have gotten past the original error, by populating a ViewBag with the strADList prior to the Return Json in my controller and changing the partial view to:                        @modeltype List(Of String) @Html.DropDownList("Emp_Mgr_Name", New SelectList(ViewBag.EmpMgrName))                                                However, this is only executing on the initial load - when I change the Emp_Mgr_Last_Name field, it is not firing the Ajax function again.

Comment: As you are using MVC3 you can remove "/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" as it is there for backwards compatibility with MVC1-2, Microsoft now advise to use the jQuery Ajax stuff (in MVC4 the scripts will be removed last I read)